# What is the best way to loop through an index of an array to search for a certain letter?

Tags: javascript

This code currently does the job I am asking for, but I was wondering if there was a better way, as calling `names[i][j]` seems impractical.

```js
var names = ["Jensen", "Cody", "Darren", "Styles", "Rhyjen"];
for(var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    for(var j = 0; j < names[i].length; j++) {
        if(names[i][j] === "J" || names[i][j] === "j") {
            console.log("Name with the letter J detected!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the result of all? a flag? or some other action?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `includes` method in combination with `filter` method which applies a `provided` callback method to every item in the array.

```js
var names = ["Jensen", "Cody", "Darren", "Styles", "Rhyjen"];
console.log(names.filter(a=>a.toLowerCase().includes("j")));
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to lowercase your names using `a.toLowercase.includes("j")`?

Answer (score 2):

Simply use with [`indexOf('j')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) .Iterate with array with  `Array#forEach` then convert the each text into `lowercase`.Then match the indexof `j`

```js
var names = ["Jensen", "Cody", "Darren", "Styles", "Rhyjen"];
names.forEach(a => a.toLowerCase().indexOf('j') > -1? console.log('Name with the letter J detected!'):'')
```

Comment: `.forEach` would be more appropriate than `.map`, since you are not doing anything with the returnvalue.

Answer (score 1):

If you...

- ...want to detect that there's at least one occurrence of a given criteria, use `Array.prototype.some`.
- ...want to get the first occurrence of a given criteria, use `Array.prototype.find`.
- ...want to get all occurrences of a given criteria, use `Array.prototype.filter`.

```js
var names = ["Jensen", "Cody", "Darren", "Styles", "Rhyjen"];

var someHasJ = names.some(n => n.toLowerCase().includes("j"));
var hasJ = names.find(n => n.toLowerCase().includes("j"));
var allWithJ = names.filter(n => n.toLowerCase().includes("j"));

if (someHasJ) {
  console.log("Name with the letter J detected!");
}

if (hasJ) {
  console.log(hasJ);
}


if (allWithJ.length > 0) {
  console.log(allWithJ);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) for joining all items and check with [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```js
var names = ["Jensen", "Cody", "Darren", "Styles", "Rhyjen"];

if (names.join().toLowerCase().indexOf('j') !== -1) {
    console.log('found!');
} else {
    console.log('not found!');
}
```

Comment: I think its `two` `j's` in the array arguments.But you are out with one.you are not iterating the arguments

Answer (score 0):

Just use something like this, using some() and indexOf():

```
var names = ["Jensen", "Cody", "Darren", "Styles", "Rhyjen"];

function hasThis(arr, str){
  return arr.some(function(x) {
    return x.toLowerCase().indexOf(str.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  });
}

hasThis(names, 'J'); //return true
hasThis(names, 'Xhj'); //return false
```